# Having Remote Desktop in Full screen view

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to have Remote Desktop running in Full Screen mode ? Like it is possible to have with Real VNC, for instance.

Comment: Are you using the term Remote Desktop literally, as in Microsoft's RDC client for Mac, connecting to a Windows Server? Or Remote Desktop as in Screen Sharing (which is mac-to-mac, or to a VNC server)?

Comment: No sorry. It's the app "Remote Desktop" that comes with Apple OS X.

Comment: Screen Sharing :P

Comment: @VxJasonxV Actually, [Apple] Remote Desktop — commonly known as ARD — is the name of the client application that accesses Screen Sharing on the target machine http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/ Pierre's question is fine.

Comment: ARD is *an* application name, yes. However, neither the binary nor the protocol are called "Remote Desktop". Also, ARD doesn't "come with" OSX, so no, Pierre's comment (which I was responding to) is not fine. It's the wrong name and only causes confusion.

Comment: Ah, I agree that "comes with" is misleading. But the remote administration client binary (to which I assumed he was referring) isn't called Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: it's a fullscreen icon]

In 3.3.2 you can have it running full screen by clicking the fullscreen icon; but the client will only appear in full screen mode if it has the same resolution. Smaller resolutions will be surrounded by a black box.

I haven't tried this: but clients with higher resolutions will probably full the screen if they have the same aspect ratio, but they might look a bit funky.

Comment: That's right ! I always had this toolbar hidden. And there is no corresponding Command Menu for that ! Thanks !

Comment: IIRC, equal or higher resolutions will full screen no matter what. Lower resolutions will not. Not equal only.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside - "Screen Sharing" actually is just a VNC client.  You can a different VNC client to connect to the remote Mac as well, doesn't have to be screen sharing.

Comment: But you do have to set up a password I think for the remote one if connecting to the screen sharing 'service' if you will, without setting up another VNC server.

Comment: Mac-to-Mac Screen Sharing leverages VNC, but has some extra special things on top. If you're going to use any other VNC client, you MUST configure a VNC password. There's a big difference between Mac-to-Mac screen sharing (which allows you to log in as a system user), and *-to-Mac VNC (which needs you to configure one static password).